# Bridge Full Wave Rectifier

Tags: diodes

I'm trying to do a problem for class and I'm having trouble on clarification and where to start.
[image]

[image]

I understand how the turns ratio works, but I don't know how to find it here.  I can't find anything in my book or in handouts; I only find them when there are resistors on both sides.

I'm also confused on what VL and Vp are.  I think Vp is the peak of the whole wave but I don't know what VL is showing here.  Vrpp is also confusing me.  I just need some clarification and guidance.

Thanks

Comment: \$V_L\$ is the load voltage. \$V_p\$ and \$V_s\$ are the primary and secondary voltages.  \$V_{r\ PP}\$ is the peak-to-peak voltage on \$V_L\$.

Comment: Ohhh, that makes more sense.  So since the voltage across the load is 10, the turns ratio would then be 1:11?  Or would I have to take into account the .7 per diode used then use that voltage?

Comment: You need to take diode drops and ripple into account. They made it a bit more difficult by specifying RMS output voltage rather than average.

Answer (score 1):

Since Vp is given as 110 Vrms, it must be the RMS voltage of the power source, not the peak of anything. VL is given as 10 V rms, so it must be the RMS value of the voltage at that point including Vr(pp), the peak to peak ripple voltage. You mostly need to work backwards from VL.

Comment: So how would I go about working backwards, would I have to take the load value and bring it back through the two diodes and take that value to find the secondary peak and turns ratio?

Comment: First find the rectified but unfiltered peak value and filter capacitor value that will give the filtered VL voltage with the specified ripple.